# Special UIlabel design

Tags: ios, user-interface, uilabel

I am developing an iOS application and I would like to style a `UILabel` like this image. [image http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_388558Capturedcran20120629142330.png](http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_388558Capturedcran20120629142330.png)

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to create a `UILabel`as normally, and then put an black `UIView` on top of the empty part of the `UILabel`. You can actually calculate where it should be putted, based on the size of the text's font.

Comment: i would like just to put the green background to the UIlabel

Comment: `[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

Comment: héhé ima sorry, i am not good in english, how a can do like the image ?

Comment: It's not an image, it's a property of the `UILabel` that let's you set the `backgroundColor` of it. If you want to set the RGB =>     `[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:12.0 blue:12.0 alpha:1.0]];`

Comment: @JackyBoy colorWithRed takes CGFloats between 0 and 1. Anything above 1.0 is evaluated to be 1.0

Comment: You usually divide by 255.0 for RGB values, e.g. colorWithRed:240.0/255.0

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to add a UILabel as a subview of a wrapper UIView

```
// Using ARC

// Set Wrapper
CGRect wrapperFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
UIView *specialLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:wrapperFrame];
[specialLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

// Set Content
CGFloat padding = 10;
CGRect contentFrame = CGRectInset(wrapperFrame, padding, padding);
UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
[contentLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

// Append content to wrapper
[specialLabel addSubview:contentLabel];
```